# Get existing folder in batch scripting

Tags: batch-file

May I know how to get the lastest folder with "FullBuild" naming from project path?

In my /PROJ path, there are 5 folders consists of 'Build' or 'FullBuild' folder as following:

1. 2017-02-01_10-00 |-Build_110053
2. 2017-02-02_10-00 |-FullBuild_120043
3. 2017-02-03_10-00 |-Build_105043
4. 2017-02-04_10-00 |-FullBuild_120043
5. 2017-02-05_10-00 |-Build_105043

My attempt command

```
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /a:d /b /o:d "%PROJ%\*\FullBuild_*"') do set "lastFullBuild=%%F"
echo Last Full Build is: %lastFullBuild%
```

> The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
>   Last Full Build is 2017-02-05_10-00

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir\project"
SET "fullbuild=None found"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /ad /o-n "%sourcedir%\*" 2^>nul'
) DO (
 FOR /f "delims=" %%f IN (
  'dir /b /ad "%sourcedir%\%%a\Fullbuild_*" 2^>nul'
 ) DO SET "fullbuild=%%a"&GOTO found
 )
)

:found
ECHO Last full build : %fullbuild%

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

Sunce your parent directory-names for the `fullbuild` directory are formatted as YYYYMMDDhhmm, then reading those directories in reverse-name order (/o-n) will process in reverse-date order.

With each directory-name in `%%a`, see whether there is a `fullbuild` directory below it. If there is, assign the name of the parent and terminate the loop forcefully with that name in `fullbuild`. If no `fullbuild` directories are found at all, the `None found` value will survive the loops.

Note the use of `2^>nul` within the `dir` commands to suppress the error message should no results be found. `2>nul` suppresses the error report, and the caret escapes the redirector to tell `cmd` that the redirector is part of the `dir`, not of the `for`.